# VPN not working well on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

I have installed a fresh copy of `Ubuntu 16.04` while being connected to the internet. 
As many websites are filtered by my `ISP`, I am using a `pptp VPN` service.
Problem is that many sites which were filtered before are now accessible,  while many others sites like `Youtube`... are still out of reach.
I suspected my `DNS` might have problems, therefore I added `prepend domain-name-servers my-ISP-DNS1, my-ISP-DNS2;` to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, installed `nscd` and restarted it but no positive results I earned. The following is the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And my `/etc/resolv.cong` only contains `127.0.0.1` as NameServer address. 
This is also `ifconfig` command's output:

```
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:5b:76:93:9d:42  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:e1300000-e1320000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:120823 (120.8 KB)  TX bytes:120823 (120.8 KB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 58:fb:84:49:69:b6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ac69:e917:959e:bd56/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17995 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16753408 (16.7 MB)  TX bytes:3284472 (3.2 MB)
```

Would you help me figure out what the problem might be with my installation?

Comment: I suggest using Open VPN. Mine works great and my VPN provides files I can just "click on" for setup.

Comment: As I tried the `ip address show` command after activating the vpn I saw the following interface being shown: `8: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
    inet 168.158.28.75 peer 80.84.49.159/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`  . What is it and why is it `NOARP` instead of being `ARP`?